# BCD Issue - 0xc000000d - the requested system device cannot be found

Tags: windows-8, boot, bcd

My notebook was working fine yesterday.
Today, when I turned it on I got the following screen:

```
    Recovery
    --------
    Your PC needs to be repaired

    The Boot Configuration Data file is missing some required information.
    File: \BCD
    Error code: 0xc000000d

    You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer.
```

I have followed the steps provided on this article: http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/surface-rt-startup-error-0xc000000d

Step 3: When prompted, choose your language options and keyboard layout.

Step 4: Tap or click Troubleshoot.

Step 5: Tap or click Advanced Options.

Step 6: Tap or click Command Prompt.

Step 7: From the BitLocker screen, tap on the screen to hide the touch keyboard and then tap or click Skip This Drive at the bottom of the screen.

Step 8: At the command prompt,

Type bootrec /rebuildbcd, and then press Enter.

When asked “Add installation to boot list? Yes (Y) No (N) All (A)” for c:\Windows, type the letter Y , and then press Enter.

At this point I got the following error:

**"the requested system device cannot be found"**

I'm stuck on this point.

Can't use my PC.

Can't find a solution for my issue.

Comment: Try completely rebuilding the BCD https://neosmart.net/wiki/bootrec/#bootrec_RebuildBcd_doesn8217t_work

Comment: @RsyaStudios, I had tried that before...didn't work

Comment: Sounds like a faulty hard drive or at least failed sectors containing bootrec data, install a new drive and use your recovery media to get windows installed, once in windows, shut down and connect the old drive as a secondary hard drive, boot into windows and see if you can pull any data off of it.